# How can I write an effective array-like structure that has a custom index range in Scala?

Tags: arrays, scala, scala-collections

I want something like the variable-index arrays of Pascal, where the user specifies the valid index range.  Instead of having the default choices for indexing its contents be 0 through length-1, I want the first index to be, say 10,000, and the last to be 20,000.

Scala is so flexible, it’s a sure thing what I want is doable.  However, discipline would be required to create a data structure that harmonize with the rest of the collections.

One “obvious” solution might be to simply specify the size to be 20,000 and waste the first half of memory, but that’s no good.  Also, a map structure could be made to work in a jiffy. But the overhead involved with HashMap is an order of magnitude that of an array-like structure such as I’m describing.

Ideally, it shouldn’t repeat or reinvent already existing code, nor should it be unduly complex, even internally.

As an example of what I want, consider an array which has valid indexes from 500 to 999.  I'll call my class an IndexedArray, to distinguish it from the standard array used in Scala.  Also, I'll use the traditional range from Scala to specify the index range in declaration.

To keep things simple, I do not need my data structure to have a stride different from one.  All the indexes will be contiguous.

```
var histogram = new IndexedArray[Int](500 to 999)
histogram(500) = 10  // "first" entry has value 10
histogram(999) += 1  // "last" entry has value 1
```

Of course, the problem could be solved by simply using a standard Scala array, and remapping the index with every access.  But isn't that a recipe for bugs?  I want the data structure to hide that little detail from my eyes.

My data structure will, of course, be mutable, since standard arrays in Scala are mutable; and the only difference in behavior is that the index will be automatically remapped with every access.

Comment: I'd probably just extend the `List` class and offset the indexes everytime an operation is applied on the list. For example, `MyList(12000)` just becomes `List(12000-10000)`

Comment: For those unfamiliar with Pascal, could you briefly sketch what exactly you mean by "variable-index arrays", what does it look like, purely from the syntactic point of view? Also, is the range 10k-20k contiguous (only offset), or should it be possible to have a non-1 "stride"?

Comment: @xbonez If you wanted to find a linear sequence collection that is as non-mutable-array-like as possible, that would be `List`.

Comment: Also, should your data structure be of fixed or variable size? In the first case, wrapping an `Array` and offsetting the indices on every access looks good enough to me.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out to be not that difficult to get at least a rudimentary structure that now works as advertised.  I would really prefer to have my class extend the appropriate structure already in Scala collections, so as to merge invisibly with the rest of the mutable collection API.  However, I haven't been able to do this so far.

My rudimentary solution does, however, show ***some*** of the awesomeness of Scala by having the same syntax for accessing elements as a standard Scala array.

```
class IndexedArray[T: ClassTag](val range: Range)  {

  val size: Int = range.end - range.start + 1
  val start: Int = range.start
  val array = new Array[T](size)

  def apply(index: Int): T = array(index - start).asInstanceOf[T]

  lazy val elemTag: ClassTag[T] = ClassTag[T](array.getClass.getComponentType)

  def length: Int = array.length

  def update(index: Int, elem: T): Unit = array.update( index - start, elem )

}
```

One can now instantiate the data structure using the above-mentioned syntax and use the data structure as follows.  (For Scala newbies, the following two lines are equivalent and do the same thing.)

```
var pascalLike = IndexedArray[Int](500 until 1000)
```

or

```
var pascalLike = IndexedArray[Int](500 to 999)
```

Then, we can use the structure.

```
pascalLike(500) = 100          // Sets the first element to 100
pascalLike(500) += 1           // Adds 1 to the first element
pascalLike(501) -= 2           // Subtracts 2 from the second element
println(pascalLike(501))       // Prints "-2"
```

What I don't know is how to make this structure "flow" with the rest of the Scala collections API.  For example, I would like the `zipWithIndex` index method to work the way one might expect for a data structure like this, using the indices appropriate to the structure.

Right now, the only way to merge this guy is to grab the underlying `array` member and hope the Scala compiler allows implicit conversion that harmonizes with what the user is wanting to do, which doesn't quite meet my original goals.